# Tomee 9 with jax-rs always returns error 404 not found

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jax-rs, apache-tomee

I am trying to create a simple Rest API with Java 11, jax-rs and Tomee Plume 9 for the server.
After many conflicts between `javax.X` and `jakarta.X`, I was finally able to compile the project.
But when I try to run it on Intellij Idea, I get a 404 error on all my requests...
I have no errors in the logs.

Here my web.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee
                      https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee/web-app_5_0.xsd"
         version="5.0"
         metadata-complete="true">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>fr.theogiraudet.rest</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

And an extract of my Rest resource, located in the package `fr.theogiraudet.rest`:

```java
@Path("/pianos")
public class PianoResource {

    @GET
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public Response getAllPianos(@Context UriInfo uriInfo) {
        final var optParams = filter(uriInfo);
        if (optParams.isEmpty())
            return Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST).build();

        final var listOpt = dao.getAllPianos(optParams.get());
        if (listOpt.isEmpty())
            return Response.serverError().build();

        return Response.ok().entity(listOpt.get().toArray(new Piano[0])).build();
    }
}
```

My request: GET - http://localhost:8080/api/pianos
The application context is `/`.
At server startup, the war seems to be well located and deployed, as seen in logs:

```
10-Aug-2021 21:09:58.897 INFOS [http-nio-8080-exec-4] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication Deployed Application(path=E:\Programmation\IntelliJ\Pause Piano - Backend\target\pause-piano-backend-1.0-SNAPSHOT)
10-Aug-2021 21:09:59.188 INFOS [http-nio-8080-exec-4] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars Au moins un fichier JAR a été analysé pour trouver des TLDs mais il n'en contenait pas, le mode "debug" du journal peut être activé pour obtenir une liste complète de JAR scannés sans succès ; éviter d'analyser des JARs inutilement peut améliorer sensiblement le temps de démarrage et le temps de compilation des JSPs
[2021-08-10 09:10:00,169] Artifact Pause Piano - Backend:war: Artifact is deployed successfully
[2021-08-10 09:10:00,169] Artifact Pause Piano - Backend:war: Deploy took 4,904 milliseconds
```

The project can be found here if you need more information about the code (like pom.xml):
https://github.com/Pause-Piano/PausePiano-Backend

Comment: Why does [the Dockerfile say TomEE 8](https://github.com/Pause-Piano/PausePiano-Backend/blob/54761c9a81d7b1be2177d967fcab1de0a2cd8105/Dockerfile#L1) but your post says 9?

Comment: Because the lattest version of Tomee on the docker hub is Tomee 8: https://hub.docker.com/_/tomee  
But it's not really important, because I don't use Docker for my dev tests

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## tl;dr

You are using a version of `swagger`, which does not support the `jakarta` namespace. You have to upgrade to `2.1.7` or higher and add the related `-jakarta` suffix to the artifact descriptors. In addition, you are using an unsupported jackson, which does not support `jakarta` as well. You have to switch to `jackson-jakarta-rs-providers` (see details below).

## Long explanation

To reproduce the deployment process I quickly added the following plugin configuration to your pom.xml to run TomEE from within Maven via `tomee:run`

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomee.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomee-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.7</version>
            <configuration>
                <tomeeVersion>9.0.0-M7</tomeeVersion>
                <tomeeClassifier>plume</tomeeClassifier>
                <debug>true</debug>
                <tomeeHttpPort>8282</tomeeHttpPort>
                <debugPort>5005</debugPort>
                <args>-Dfoo=bar</args>
                <config>${project.basedir}/src/test/tomee/conf</config>
                <skipCurrentProject>true</skipCurrentProject>
                <webapps>
                    <webapp>
                        fr.pause-piano:pause-piano-backend:1.0-SNAPSHOT?name=ROOT
                    </webapp>
                </webapps>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Then it tries to deploy your webapp, it will print some `ClassNotFoundExceptions` to the console output indicating some hassle between `javax` and `jakarta` namespaces.

You are using a version of `swagger`, which does not support the `jakarta` namespace. The [official repository on GitHub](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core) states:

> NOTE: Since version 2.1.7 Swagger Core supports also Jakarta
> namespace, with a parallel set of artifacts with -jakarta suffix,
> providing the same functionality as the "standard" javax namespace
> ones. Please check Wiki for more details

That means, you have to upgrade the related artifacts in and suffix in your code to:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger-jaxrs2-jakarta</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.10</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger-jaxrs2-servlet-initializer-v2-jakarta</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.10</version>
    </dependency>
```

However, this will not be sufficient as the webapp is still using an  unsupported jackson version, which does not support the `jakarta` namespace (see [GitHub](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-jaxrs-providers)):

> (*) NOTE! JAX-RS is the "old" API defined under javax.ws.rs; in 2019
> or so, Oracle decided to force a forking of this into "Jakarta"
> variant under jakarta.ws.ws. As of 2021 most frameworks still use the
> old API but if you do need/want to use newer one, check out Jakarta-RS
> provider repo at jackson-jakarta-rs-providers

You have to switch to `jackson-jakarta-rs-providers` by replacing the jackson dependency in your project with

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jakarta.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-jakarta-rs-json-provider</artifactId>
        <version>2.13.0-rc2</version>
    </dependency>
```

After applying these changes, the webapp will still throw another `ClassNotFoundException`. Using `mvn dependency:tree`, we can see, that the updated `swagger-jaxrs2-jakarta` pulls in a `jackson-jaxrs-provider` dependency. Odd, isn't it? So we need to exclude it:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger-jaxrs2-jakarta</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.10</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

After that change, we can give it another try by running `mvn clean install` and `mvn tomee:run`. The log output logs good and shows the deployed endpoints:

```
31-Aug-2021 14:46:20.894 INFORMATION [main] org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener.logEndpoints REST Application: http://localhost:8282/sample                          -> fr.theogiraudet.swagger.Swagger@f25176a
31-Aug-2021 14:46:20.903 INFORMATION [main] org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener.logEndpoints      Service URI: http://localhost:8282/sample/openapi                  -> Pojo io.swagger.v3.jaxrs2.integration.resources.AcceptHeaderOpenApiResource
31-Aug-2021 14:46:20.903 INFORMATION [main] org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener.logEndpoints               GET http://localhost:8282/sample/openapi                  ->      Response getOpenApiJson(HttpHeaders, UriInfo) throws Exception
31-Aug-2021 14:46:20.903 INFORMATION [main] org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener.logEndpoints               GET http://localhost:8282/sample/openapi                  ->      Response getOpenApiYaml(HttpHeaders, UriInfo) throws Exception
31-Aug-2021 14:46:20.905 INFORMATION [main] org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener.logEndpoints      Service URI: http://localhost:8282/sample/openapi.{type:json|yaml} -> Pojo io.swagger.v3.jaxrs2.integration.resources.OpenApiResource            
31-Aug-2021 14:46:20.905 INFORMATION [main] org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener.logEndpoints               GET http://localhost:8282/sample/openapi.{type:json|yaml} ->      Response getOpenApi(HttpHeaders, UriInfo, String) throws Exception
31-Aug-2021 14:46:20.905 INFORMATION [main] org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener.logEndpoints      Service URI: http://localhost:8282/sample/pianos                   -> Pojo fr.theogiraudet.rest.PianoResource                                    
31-Aug-2021 14:46:20.905 INFORMATION [main] org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener.logEndpoints            DELETE http://localhost:8282/sample/pianos                   ->      Response deleteAllPianos()    
31-Aug-2021 14:46:20.906 INFORMATION [main] org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener.logEndpoints               GET http://localhost:8282/sample/pianos                   ->      Response getAllPianos(UriInfo)
31-Aug-2021 14:46:20.906 INFORMATION [main] org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener.logEndpoints               GET http://localhost:8282/sample/pianos/{id}              ->      Response getPiano(int)        
31-Aug-2021 14:46:20.906 INFORMATION [main] org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener.logEndpoints              POST http://localhost:8282/sample/pianos                   ->      Response postPiano(PianoData) 
31-Aug-2021 14:46:20.956 INFORMATION [main] jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Deployment of web application archive [/home/zowallar/IdeaProjects/PausePiano-Backend/target/apache-tomee/webapps/ROOT.war] has finished in [4.433] ms
31-Aug-2021 14:46:20.968 INFORMATION [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.setClassLoaderProperty Unable to set the web application class loader property [clearReferencesRmiTargets] to [true] as the property does not exist.
31-Aug-2021 14:46:20.969 INFORMATION [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.setClassLoaderProperty Unable to set the web application class loader property [clearReferencesObjectStreamClassCaches] to [true] as the property does not exist.
31-Aug-2021 14:46:20.969 INFORMATION [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.setClassLoaderProperty Unable to set the web application class loader property [clearReferencesObjectStreamClassCaches] to [true] as the property does not exist.
31-Aug-2021 14:46:20.969 INFORMATION [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.setClassLoaderProperty Unable to set the web application class loader property [clearReferencesThreadLocals] to [true] as the property does not exist.
31-Aug-2021 14:46:20.989 INFORMATION [main] jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8282"]
31-Aug-2021 14:46:21.003 INFORMATION [main] jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Server startup in [4564] milliseconds
```

However, invoking a related endpoints leads to another exception:

```
jakarta.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet [fr.theogiraudet.swagger.Swagger] threw exception
    org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:45)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:543)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBSecurityListener$RequestCapturer.invoke(OpenEJBSecurityListener.java:97)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:690)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:353)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:870)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1696)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

caused by

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The resource configuration is not modifiable in this context.
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig$ImmutableState.register(ResourceConfig.java:248)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig$ImmutableState.register(ResourceConfig.java:195)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig.register(ResourceConfig.java:428)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:306)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:154)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:347)
    jakarta.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:45)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:543)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBSecurityListener$RequestCapturer.invoke(OpenEJBSecurityListener.java:97)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:690)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:353)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:870)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1696)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

Looking into the log reveals some issues with `jackson`:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/module/jaxb/JaxbAnnotationIntrospector
```

## Summary

It looks like, that the related tooling (`swagger`) in combination with `jackson` is not yet ready to fully work with the `jakarta` namespace. if you are not torn to use 9, you could simply switch to 8 with working tooling (as 9 only contains namespace changes).

Comment: Thanks you very much for all this explanation!